# JInternalFrame bottom shadow issue

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I am creating an application that uses many JInternalFrames, but whenever I add one to my JDesktopPane, the bottom shadow of the internal frame is opaque and dark gray, as shown below. Is this an issue with the look and feel and is there a way to fix this without removing the shadow altogether?

[image]

Edit: Here's some runnable code which demonstrates an internal frame having an issue with the bottom shadow even when using the most basic form:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDesktopPane pane = new JDesktopPane();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    pane.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(pane);
    JInternalFrame intFrame = new JInternalFrame();
    intFrame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
    intFrame.setVisible(true);
    intFrame.setResizable(true);
    pane.add(intFrame);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fix this" and by "without removing the shadow altogether"? What would a "fixed" screen look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just in case someone with the same problem stumbles upon this post, it turns out this was a problem with java in OS X El Capitan, and I'm not currently aware of a fix for it.

Answer (score 2):

You've overridden the `paint(Component)` of the `JInternalFrame` directly instead of using something like a `JPanel`, using its `paintComponent` method to do the custom painting and then adding this to the `JInternalFrame`'s `contentPane`

Just like a `JFrame`, a `JInternalFrame` has a `JRootPane`, which has a `contentPane` and all this is wrapped in a frame decoration, by overriding its `paint(Component)` directly, you are actually painting beneath the frame decorations, so that the grey area at the bottom will actually be the height of the title area, which you are painting under

This, of course, is all guess work based on observation of simular issues, but since you've not provided any runnable example, it's the best I can do

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I overrode the paint method. However when I create just a generic JInternalFrame and add it to my JDesktopPane, the gray area is still there, which is why I initially thought it could be a L&F issue.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I added a short little program, but I have a feeling this will only demonstrate the problem on a mac